# SocketConnection exception with OkHttp even though it should retry on connection failure

Tags: kotlin, sockets, okhttp

What could be causing a SocketConnection exception despite using OkHttpClient with retryOnConnectionFailure set to true(default)? We are using okHttpClientVersion = "4.10.0" with Kotlin and have introduced an interceptor to close the socket connection in case of a server IP change. Multiple calls are running in parallel, and if the interceptor closes the socket in one connection, every other connection that's in progress fails, resulting in a SocketException.

According to the documentation (https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.0.1/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#retryOnConnectionFailure-boolean-), OkHttpClient will retry if it sees stale pooled connections. Therefore, it should retry and get a new socket connection on the next retry, and it should work. However, we are still getting SocketConnection exceptions. What could be causing this issue?